# "Reset keyboard dictionary" option missing in iOS Simulator settings

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I am running an iPhone 11 Simulator running iOS 13 and doing some typing simulations via a testing framework.
After finishing typing I would like to delete the keyboard dictionary (ie. wipe the new words that the keyboard learned as I typed). 
Resetting the keyboard dictionary is possible on a real device by going to "Settings" -> "General" > "Reset" -> tap "Reset Keyboard Dictionary", but this option seems to be missing on the simulator.

Does anyone know why this option is missing on the emulator and how to (if possible) bring it up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that whilst the simulator is the main window, you can select `Harware->Erase All Content and Settings...` and this will delete the keyboard dictionary, along with many other settings/preferences.

[image]

Comment: yes but this option will wipe the whole device. And require a reboot. I do not want to do that

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but a workaround to your question but if you can't find any other solution you can reset the whole device (it's like a factory reset) from menu `Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings` or from command line using `xcrun simctl erase booted`